# Incomplete Gamma function for negative values

Tags: matlab, mathematical-expressions, gamma-distribution, gamma-function

I was deriving an expression for truncated gamma distribution. I derived an expression for the same which include incomplete gamma function. When I was implementing the same in matlab using the 'gammainc(x,alpha)' function, I was getting complex values because my x values are negative. Is there is any other way to compute incomplete gamma function for negative values?

Comment: Why do you want some other way to compute the function for negative `x`? Are the values produced by `gammainc` not correct?

Comment: If you need to work with a truncated Gamma distribution, have you considered the [probability distribution objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/working-with-probability-distributions.html) available such as `pd = truncate(makedist('Gamma',alpha,beta),a,b)`?  Then pdf, cdf, inverse cdf (for quantiles) and other things are immediately available.

Comment: @LuisMendo the values produced by gammainc is correct only, but when I am finding gammaincinv, then the values must be in [0 1].

Comment: @SecretAgentMan Thank you! I also derived a closed form expression for the same now. I will check both. Thank you once again!

Comment: @AnilRamachnadran, excellent.  I'd encourage you to post your own answer to help future visitors to this post.